# (Python/Django) How to do object-level custom validations in the models?

Tags: python, django-models, django-rest-framework

In Django/python, is there a way to do object-level custom validations in the models?

models.py:

```
class User(AbstractUser):
    SUPPLY = 'Supply'
    DEMAND = "Demand"

    USER_TYPES = [
        (SUPPLY, 'Supply'),
        (DEMAND, 'Demand')
    ]

    user_type = models.CharField(
        max_length=20,
        choices=USER_TYPES,
    )

    username = models.CharField(max_length=50, unique=True)
    email = models.CharField(max_length=50, unique=True)
    profile_picture_url = models.CharField(max_length=250)
    country = models.CharField(max_length=50, blank=True)
```

I'd like the `country` field to be required only for supply users, and for an error to be raised when the field isn't filled at the registration form submission, alongside the other validation errors in the same response dictionary/object, if there are any.

Something like this:

```
    def validate_country(self):
        if (self.user_type == self.HELPSEEKER) and (not self.country or self.country == ''):
            raise ValidationError({'country': ['This field may not be blank.']})
```

I've tried validation in the serializer but it's not ideal in terms of user experience as the error is only raised once that all the model conditions have been fulfilled.

Currently, this is the user serializer:

```
class UserSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    password = serializers.CharField(write_only=True)
    password_confirmation = serializers.CharField(write_only=True)

    def validate(self, data):
        password = data.pop('password')
        password_confirmation = data.pop('password_confirmation')

        if password != password_confirmation:
            raise ValidationError({'password_confirmation': 'Passwords do not match'})

        if (data['user_type'] == 'Supply') and (not data['country'] or data['country'] == ''):
            raise ValidationError({'country': ['This field may not be blank.']})

        try:
            validations.validate_password(password=password)
        except ValidationError as err:
            raise ValidationError({'password': err.messages})

        data['password'] = make_password(password)

        return data

    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = '__all__'
```

Comment: What did you mean by `only raised once the model conditions have been fulfilled.`? Custom validation can still cover this even though model conditions are there.

Comment: I mean that, say the model has a required field `username`, and a `country` field not required. In the instance that the `country` field is required for a single user type, not the other, if I fulfill the `username` requirement but not the `country`, I will get the validation error for the `country` (great, I would expect that). If I don't fill the `username` field and the country field, I will only get a validation error for the `username` (not both errors simultaneously). I've tweaked stuff at the front end but would've preferred an easier/simpler solution.

Comment: I've tried this again and it works with both the required field in the model, plus any custom serializer validations on any other fields, and returning errors on both in the same response/serializer.errors field. Can you update your problem description with the current serializer implementation you have?

Comment: Also it might not be working because you named the validation as `validate_supply_country` but it should be just `validate_country` based on your models?

Comment: Just updated it now. I made a mistake when I wrote the example code on the post above. Nevertheless, I cannot use field-level validation because I need other elements of the dictionary to create conditionals. I just tested the backend again, if I omit country and username fields, I just get an error for the username (which is required in the models), and if I put all field correctly but the country, I finally get the error message. I'd like to get the error message for username + country at the same time.

Comment: Oh I see the problem now. DRF behaviour is `validate_country` will never be called if `country` is not in the data. And you can't use `validate` for this if username is missing, because you are right, the model validation will come first and end without calling `validate`. Is it not an option for you to always send country, just expecting it to be blank or null at times? This will make sure `validate_country` will always be called. You can just add some code to do nothing in the validate if it is blank

Comment: Right, we're getting somewhere. So `not data['country']` is just an extra precaution, but essentially, I'm always sending `country` whether empty string or not, from the front end. But, the prob is that it's ok to be blank if the user type is **Demand**, but it's required to be filled if its user type is **Supply**. That's why I use `validate` and not `validate_country` (because I need to check the user type to validate country, which will only be passed in `validate`'s `data` argument, but not in `validate_country`, unfortunately).

Comment: So is there a way to use a conditional in the user model that would do something like so: `if (data['user_type'] == 'Supply') and (not data['country'] or data['country'] == ''): raise ValidationError({'country': ['This field may not be blank.']})` (I anticipate that it's not possible)?

Comment: If you really want the validation for country to go with the username model validation, you can still use `validate_country(self, value)`, but this time use `self.initial_data` to get the `user_type`.

Comment: Yes!!!! that's what I needed. awesome, thanks for that!!!